# Toolbar visible on top of the Uncollapsed CollapsingToolbar

Tags: android, xml, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have added a CollapsingToolbarLayout which fads the background image and morphs in to a toolbar. I have implemented the code, it does morphs into a toolbar but the problem is the toolbar always stay visible even on top of the ImageView of the collapsingToolbar layout even *in uncollapsed mode*. I don't understand why is this happening. Following is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayoutForCollapsingBarActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingAppbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="290dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/chicking_riding_converted"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:title="MyToolbarTitle"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf v jkljsdflk ajsdfkj asdklfj adsklfj asklfj adsklf jasdklfj ak fjasklfj adskl fjadkl fjadskl fjakl fjaksl fjakl fjasldk fjadskl fjask fjalfj adkfj asdkl fjaklf jasklfj aklf jadsklf jadslkf jadsklf jadkfl jasdlkf jaklf jadkl fjaskl fjasklf jadskl fjadsklf jaslk fjadslkf jaslkfjadslkfasjfkl jfklasdjfksfaklj asdklfj askl fjakl jflk jflk jalksdjf adsklfjasdklfj ads jfadskl jfadkfj adskl fjadklf jadsklf jakl fj k"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

**What is causing the toolbar to behave like this?**

Answer (score 3):

That is the toolbar background. Remove this from the toolbar:

```
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
```

...and it will be transparent.

If it remains transparent when collapsed, add this to the CollapsingToolbarLayout:

```
app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
```

...and it will adopt the background color when collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
```

inside the `Toolbar` element.